# Post request with GraphQL Payload in python3

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests, graphql

Hello I'm trying to make a Post request to ProductHunt API.
In the example they provide the following payload:

```
{
"query": "query { posts(first: 1) { edges { node { id, name } } } }"
}
```

This is my Python implementation:

```
queryz =  { 'query' : '{ posts(first: 1) { edges { node { id, name } } 
} }' }

r = requests.post(url, headers=headerz, data=queryz)
r.text
```

I tried encoding the payload in Json but I always get the same response

When I do the request I always get a 400 Bad Request response, I tried the same request in Postman using GraphQL query and I get the correct response.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The issue was in the way I used the dumps function.

Using the following code, it works

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headerz, data=json.dumps(queryz))
```